# Why is this not a legal method signature?

Tags: java, methods, signature

On my practice exam, the following question was asked:

Which   of  the following   are legal   method  signatures?

```
a)  public void int foo()

b)  private static int foo()

c)  double foo(a, b)

d)  String[] foo(String a, String b)

e)  String foo(int a, String[] b)
```

I think option A is illegal, since you can't put "void" AND "int", right?

I think option B is fine, and I THOUGHT option C was legal too, but the answer key marks C as an illegal method signature.

I'm having trouble understanding why options D and E are legal, but option C isn't? Any ideas?

Comment: Look at (c) closely and verify that it contains ALL the necessary bits.

Comment: (c) doesn't declare the types of its parameters

Comment: You could run it through the nearest compiler and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double foo(a, b)
```

The types of the parameters are missing.